# How to dismiss all open Alert Dialogs without any references

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a restart option in my game. but the problem is that there may be some open alertdialog in the existing activity when I press restart.

When I press restart I want to dismiss all open Alertdialog(if any). I do not have any reference to opened up alertdialogs(Can be o,1 or more than one).

Is there any way I can dismiss all the opened up alertdialogs in the activity at any time without having any reference to it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First you could assign all your dialogs to a member variable, e.g.

```
private Vector<AlertDialog> dialogs = new Vector<AlertDialog>();

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
  switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_ALERT:
      Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      ...
      AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
      dialogs.add(dialog);
      dialog.show();
   }
   return super.onCreateDialog(id);
}
```

Afterwards, you can test whether dialogs are showing or not by using the `isShowing()` method of your dialogs (check out inherited methods from class `android.app.Dialog`http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html), e.g.

```
public void closeDialogs() {
   for (AlertDialog dialog : dialogs)
      if (dialog.isShowing()) dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Or you might finish and start your activity again as *Pragnani* said. Depends on where your restart button is ...